# Mount smb share as local directory

Tags: macos, sharing, mount, file, smb

I want to use GIT and directory should be on a network drive (mounted with `smb://`). Because the software I'm using only supports the `file://` protocol I need some kind of mapping the network share as a local drive on Mac OS X 10.9. How can that be managed?

Comment: Do you see the mounted Samba volume under `/Volumes/NAME-OF-DRIVE`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand how mounting works. In short what you want is to:

1. Mount your `smb://` drive on a certain location.
2. Use your `file://` command as you always do.

When you use 'Connect to Server' - <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, your drive should be mounted somewhere in `/Volumes/`. So now you can use `file://Volumes/drive-name`.

For normal use, like this, a mounted network filesystems can be treated just like a 'local' file system. There is no difference in use.

*How to mount network drives automatically is another story and can be found on SO, for example https://superuser.com/a/367730/246895*

Comment: The `/Volumes/` helped me out here. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: If your are not afraid for the terminal, you can use the `mount` command to find mount pionts.